# Google Analytics User timings - Page Usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google analytics user timings api to track Page Usage (Track how long the user stays on the **Specific** Page).

1. Initialize start Time when user navigate to Page ( Eg. User Details Page )

   ```
   document.onreadystatechange = function() {var startUserTrackTime = new  Date();}
   ```
2. User fill up data (Name, Age) **FYI -No post back/no operations performed as simple as that**
3. Navigate to other pages **(Track the time now)**

   ```
   window.onunload = function () {
       trackPageUsage();
   }

   function trackPageUsage() {

       if (startUserTrackTime) {
           ga('send',
           {
               timingCategory: 'xx',
               timingVar: 'xx',
               timingValue: new Date().getTime() - startUserTrackTime.getTime(),
               timingLabel: 'xxx'
           });

       }
   }
   ```

Doubts points:

User stays for 10 minutes (User Details Page).Will the code work to get correct milliseconds:

```
timingValue: new Date().getTime() - startUserTrackTime.getTime()
```

Approach to track time for specific page is correct or possible fault is seen.

Don't want to use Performance API (Does not suit my requirement)